# C# code written in Visual Studio won't run in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-code, console-application

I am trying to run a .NET Core Application in Visual Studio Code that was created in Visual Studio 2019. I'm having trouble with the dotnet run part, though. It keeps giving me this error:

> Unable to run your project.
>   Ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project.
>   A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance, netcoreapp2.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'.
>   The current OutputType is 'Exe'.

I have tried dotnet restore, dotnet build, dotnet clean, etc. Any suggestions on how to get this to run?

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZGNr.png)

Comment: Well, what TFM do you have?

Comment: Have you ensured that the required .NET Core Packages are installed that are needed to build; these are required for the build assets.

Comment: Have you changed something in the sln or csproj? Maybe define a startup project

Comment: Same problem here. I'm building a simple test Azure function, with a fresh start in both VS2019 and VSCode to compare the IDEs. Both work at first, but then copying code from the VS2019 project to the VSCode project causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your problem, but I experienced something similar recently. Some applications coded in VS will not run in VS Code. VS 2019 utilizes IIS Express to run applcations on localhost. I do not believe VS Code has this ability as a text editor, compared to the power of VS 2019 as a IDE.